# Algorithm for finding record with most matching attributes

Tags: algorithm, search, theory

I'm looking for some algorithm that for a given record with n properties with n possible values each (int, string etc) searches a number of existing records and gives back the one that matches the most properties.

Example:

```
A = 1
B = 1
C = 1
D = f

A   | B   | C   | D
----+-----+-----+----
1   | 1   | 9   | f    <
2   | 3   | 1   | g
3   | 4   | 2   | h
2   | 5   | 8   | j
3   | 6   | 5   | h
```

The first row would be the one I'm looking for, as it has the most matching values. I think it doesn't need to calculate any closeness to the values, because then row 2 might be more matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each row, add one to the row score of a field matches (field one has a score of 2) and when that's done, you have a resultset of scores which you can sort.

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm could look like (in java pseudo code):

```
int bestMatchIdx = -1;
int currMatches = 0;
int bestMatches = 0;

for ( int row = 0 ; row < numRows ; row++ ) {
   currMatches = 0;
   for ( int col = 0 ; col < numCols ; col++ ) {
       if ( search[col].equals( rows[ row ][ cols] ))
            currMatches++;
   }
   if ( currMatches > bestMatches ) {
        bestMatchIdx = row;
        bestMatches = currMatches;
   }
}
```

This assumes that you have an equals function to compare, and the data stored in a 2D array. 'search' is the reference row to compare all other rows against it.